# How to securely use cronjobs

Tags: php, security, cron

How should I secure my cronjobs from being visited by search engines/visitors that write the correct URL in the headline?

I have a cronjob, that is running every night, which transfers information to MailChimp, but if a user enters the URL correctly, he can make the cronjob run at anytime. How can I avoid this? :)

Hope you have some ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the script somewhere that is not accessible from the web

Answer (score 1):

the files should be outside the web root, there's no need for them to be inside if they are only being called by cron. hope you are calling the file path and not the url?

Comment: And I hope you do now allow relative paths!

Comment: Well, it is actually a part of my application in my MVC framework, because I am using the models to retrieve data from the database, but then I probably should use another approach on this and instead move them away from the application :)

Answer (score 1):

Try for example:

```
1 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/denlau/cron.php
```

I hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution (without changing the architecture of your application) would be putting the URL which runs this cron job under authentication. May be [HTTP/S basic auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to start with. This will give you some protection.

But in longer terms, having a cron running on a URL hit seems like a bad idea to me. If possible, you should rethink about the architecture.